# How to position statusbar on top of OPENGL?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, opengl

The problem that I'm having at the moment is that OpenGL overlaps my status bar, whereas the menu of the window doesn't change. Any ideas how to solve this issue? to make statusbar on top just like the menu.

I use CreateWindowEx for both the main window (custom WNDCLASS) and the statusbar(STATUSCLASSNAME) with WS_CHILD enabled. Maybe I'm missing some of the flags.

PS. I don't use GLUT nor any other 3rd party libraries only Windows and OpenGL

Comment: Can you translate the z-index of your opengl scene to be further back than the status bar? Just an idea, not sure if it works

Comment: I'm not sure there is such thing. Because every window has it's own z-index in Windows

Comment: @user2448395: You should also set the CS_OWNDC flag in the WNDCLASSEX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add the `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` and `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS` styles to your OpenGL window.